# How to get word trigrams in elasticsearch

Tags: curl, lucene, elasticsearch, n-gram

I have been trying to get trigrams with elasticsearch tokenizers. I have followed tutorials at http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html and http://blog.qbox.io/multi-field-partial-word-autocomplete-in-elasticsearch-using-ngrams

Following these docs and testing the analyzer with

`curl 'localhost:9200/test/_analyze?pretty=1&analyzer=my_ngram_analyzer' -d 'FC Schalke 04'`

produces nGrams like `# FC, Sc, Sch, ch, cha, ha, hal, al, alk, lk, lke, ke, 04`

While what I want is whole word trigrams

for example trigrams for `the quick red fox jumps over the lazy brown dog` would be.

```
the quick red
quick red fox
red fox jumps
fox jumps over
jumps over the
over the lazy
the lazy brown
lazy brown dog
```

In a nutshell how can I create trgrams like above using elasticsearch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. Answer lies in the shingle filter. This mapping made it work

```
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "filter": {
            "nGram_filter": {
               "type": "shingle",
               "max_shingle_size": 3,
               "min_shingle_size": 3,
               output_unigrams:false
            }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "nGram_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding",
                  "nGram_filter"
               ]
            },
            "whitespace_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here key attributes are type->shingle and min/max shingle sizes.